# Make a Linux VMDK bootable

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, virtualbox

My high school provided us with pre-installed VM images to avoid the hassle of installing every piece of software we need to use. The downside of this is that the OS is quite slow so I was wondering if there is a way to dual-boot this image to get the full power of my laptop. Does someone know how to do that?

The file is a VMDK. The OS of the software is based on Ubuntu, I don't know the exact distro.

Comment: Dual boot could easily cause problems with your existing windows install. I would recommend using an external USB3 or eSATA drive (If you laptop supports it, i'd avoid USB2), and booting into a application called clonezilla on the VM. Then attach the external drive the VM and clone the VM to the hard drive.

Comment: Before you do too much work, see if you can give more resources to the VM: more memory, more processors, acceleration parameters, etc (make sure it's a 64-bit OS before allocating more than 4GB of memory). Also, once the OS is running, check that there is enough swap space and increase it if not.

Comment: I already maxed out the settings for vbox, didn't try the red part but I will later today. Didn't check for the swap space and will check that out as well, thanks.

Comment: @mt025, can't I just clone it onto a partition of my ssd instead of a external drive?

Comment: Have you tried using [VMware Workstation Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/playerpro-evaluation.html) instead of VBox?  (It is free for non-commercial use)

Answer (score -1):

Put this VMDK on a SSD, and enjoy. More memory to the vm will not hurt too.

Making the Vmdk bootable would not work as you expect. It really will not.

Comment: The VM is already on my SSD and I still don't like te speed.

Comment: Then, can you share what the "full power" of your laptop looks like? What is the CPU speed, ram, disk performance ? Is it really a kick ass machine?

Comment: Its an i7 6700hq, 960m and 8gb of ram, 128gb m.2 sad and a 1tb 5400rpm hdd. Programming in the VM just doesnt feel fluent if you know what I mean. The delay of typing and seeing the letters on screen is just too much for me to be satisfied. Also, I maxed out the settings of vbox